# What intervals does the "consecutive interval" comprehend?

Tags: theory, counterpoint

I'm studying 16th century counterpoint.

I'm reading 3part counterpoint with 2 species and 3 species mixed chapter.

I read that consecutive intervals must be avoided in certain situations.

Ok I get that but I don't know if the consecutive intervals also implies 3,4,6.

(I know I should avoid perfect 5th and 8.)

Comment: It would be helpful to have the full quotation from the book or website you're reading.

Answer (score 1):

"Consecutive intervals" in this case means *any* intervals. If one has several consecutive sixths, for example, the voices will start to lose their independence.

Leaving aside parallel fifths and octaves, it's generally okay to have three of the same interval in a row, but more than that is where the voices lose too much independence.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok I get that but I don't know if the consecutive intervals also implies 3,4,6.

I think with numerals `3,4,6` you meant the *intervals* third, fourth, and sixth.

I think of it this way:

Consecutive fifths and octaves are forbidden through a *relative motion rule*. The relative motion involved there is *perfect consonance intervals in parallel relative motion*. You can flip that around into a positive statement: *imperfect consonances are permitted to move by parallel motion*.

No that we have an idea of what relative motions are allowed for different types of intervals we can move are more *aesthetic based rule*: create variety, avoid monotony.  This "rule" applies to consecutive intervals. Fux's species counterpoint basically puts a limit of three on consecutive intervals. This limit applies regardless of the previous relative motion rule, because this second rule is not concerned with relative motion, but rather about monotony. So, even though parallel thirds and sixths are OK by relative motion rules, you still want to limit them to only three consecutive occurrences.

Three can be regarded as a rule of thumb, a general guide line. A piece of music won't fall apart over four consecutive thirds. And, if my memory serves, Fux has some examples in his treatise where there are four consecutive, imperfect consonances (I think thirds.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply it means don't use the same interval twice (or more!). So, if you've written voices that move in 5ths, the next move should be anything but. Using, as you say, 3,4,6 isn't repeating the interval, thus is o.k.